# pointers c++ - access violation reading location

Tags: c++, pointers

output: Access violation reading location 0x0093F3DC.

i cant seem to figure out the problem. the head and next pointers are initialized with null in respective constructors.

```
class List{ 
public: 
    node *head;
    List(void)  // Constructor      
    { 
        head = NULL; 
    }   
    void insertNode(int f)  
    {
        node *newNode;
        newNode=new node();
        newNode->value = f;
        newNode->next=head;
        head=newNode;
    }   
    void displayList()
    {
        node *ptr=head;
        while (ptr!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<ptr->value<<endl;
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
    }

    bool search( int val)
    {
        node *ptr= head;
        while (ptr!=NULL)
        {
            if(ptr->value == val)
            {
                return true;
            }
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        return false;   
    }
```

};

Comment: You are allocating a node object to ptr, then overwriting it with this->head.  What is the point of that?  Is ptr->next valid?  This is why you use a debugger to step through the code and example the variable values.

Comment: This much code is not sufficient to answer properly.

Comment: Though this function has a memory leak nevertheless You should show how you add nodes to the list.

Comment: node *ptr = head; also gives me the same problem.

im displaying all the nodes similarly, that function works fine, this one doesnt. teh debugger says unable to read memory at the if condition

Comment: @SohaibJamal More implementation details are needed to troubleshoot.  Pretty much the whole class header and cpp are necessary here.

Comment: and at times at node *ptr=head;

Comment: where did you initialize `head`?

Comment: ive edited the question and pasted my whole class. please have a look

Comment: @SohaibJamal  For example, the constructor body is a minimum to understand how the head is pointing to valid memory.  If it is set to NULL (or nullptr in C++11), and then head is never pointing to valid memory, the search method will always fail with an access violation / segmentation fault / application crash (or all of the above).

Comment: constructor is initializing head to null.
if that isnt correct than how do i go about it? i've always initialized heads with nulls

Comment: @SohaibJamal  The best I can suggest is to draw some pictures of the head, pointers, and node elements for the intended algorithm first.  Then draw a separate picture of how this implementation does it.  There are several implementation goals to consider here.  For example, most likely the head is intended to always point to the first node in the List, correct?  If so, then head can only be assigned to valid memory (e.g. a `node` instance) once.  If not, then the picture approach will help understand how head is supposed to be manipulated versus the current implementation.

Comment: that is the thing, the link list formation is fine, i make the linklist and i display it. it works fine. 
just crashes when i'm searching.

Comment: The comments above, as well as the improved searching function may resolve the issue.  If not, please review all of the posts to consider the next step.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it is better to declare only a pointer, instead of allocating a Node instance then wiping out the newly allocated memory (e.g. causing a dangling memory leak).  For example:

```
bool search( int val)
{
    //
    // Declare the pointer to traverse the data container, assign to the head
    // This works only if head is valid.  It is assumed that head is pointing 
    // to valid memory by the constructor and/or other class member functions.
    //
    node *ptr = this->head;
    while (ptr!=NULL)
    {
        if(ptr->value == val)
        {
            return true;
        }
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    return false;   
}
```

In the class implementation details above, the internal head pointer is always assigned to the newNode memory inside InsertNode.  Consequently head moves every time InsertNode is called.  Is this the desired functionality?

Comment: i dont find any difference. my code seems the same too

Comment: it just adds the newNode to the ahead of the list.

Comment: @SohaibJamal Most likely the specific linked list behaviors will have to be shown in the original question in order for the rest of us to understand.  Is the intention that the usual singly linked list behaviors are implemented?  It is not a good idea for us to make assumptions versus being shown the design / behavior goals.  So, please update the original post with the expected and intended behaviors.

Comment: its a normal singly linklist coming out of each index of an array

Comment: @SohaibJamal To clarify further, a singly linked list is being used to reverse an array?  If that is the case, then take a long hard look at a std::vector and the ability to traverse it from the end to the front by using `rbegin()` (e.g. an iterator that starts at the end and traverses to the front).  Is this for a homework assignment?

Comment: no its not to reverse. whatever the new entry is it is added to the front of the list.
taht pretty much all it does. 
i add 1 2 3, it gets stored as 3->2->1

now i want to search. searching works fine upto a few iterations, then it gets a bad address i guess

Comment: Unless there is a rule preventing use of the Standard Template Library (Standard Library in C++11), I would look at a `vector` or a `list` container to perform the data storage implementation details.  Check out [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).  The `list` container adds an element to the front with the `push_front` member function.

Comment: thank you mate but ive to do it using a inklist.
thanks anyway

Comment: @SohaibJamal Hopefully what is already posted will help resolve it.